# Mist wallet sync problem

Tags: mist, wallets, synchronization

At the moment I can't sync mist wallet for 3 days
it download block till 4,102,477 and final hundred bloks are stuck
but the numbers below (downloading chain structure) still running and running
for a whole day
wallet don't show my ballance still

Comment: Same problem here.
I removed the chaindatabase, but that didn't help also.
It is also downloading Chain structure???

Comment: Same problem for me. I read the same issue all over the internet. The devs have a lot to answer for on this issue.

Comment: please open an issue on their github